# How do I give my include access to my source folder so when the library is used it can be indirectly accessed to the source via the include file?

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

Right now I have to do this to indirectly access my source headers

```
#pragam once

#include "../src/some_folder/some_header.hpp"
```

But I want to be able to access it like this

```
#pragam once

#include "some_folder/some_header.hpp"
```

so it looks much cleaner

Basically, since I want the headers of my library to be accessed indirectly through one main header called Some_Libaray_Name.hpp. But I do not know how I would do that. Btw my library is a CMake project (C++).

Comment: You can set directory `../src` (converted to absolute path) as *include directory*. In CMake this is performed with [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) or, preferred, [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically, since I want the headers of my library to be accessed indirectly through one main header called `Some_Libaray_Name.hpp`.

If the main header includes a header, this header either needs to be a system header or it needs to be a header that is available at compile time. For this reason your classification of those headers seems questionable. I recommend moving the headers that are (possibly indirectly) included in `Some_Libaray_Name.hpp` to the directory containing the `Some_Libaray_Name.hpp` (in this case to inside a subdirectory of this `some_folder`); This provides you with a way of keeping some headers private; this isn't possible, if you simply add the source dir as include dir.

Of course you could use `target_include_directories` to add multiple include dirs though:

```
# make include and src include dirs available to targets using target_link_libraries to link some_lib
target_include_directory(some_lib PUBLIC include src)
```